# invalid conversion from void* to void (*) int error when compiling a simple signals code on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, c++11, signals

my code:

```
#include "xception.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

void bt_sighandler(int sig, struct sigcontext ctx) 
{

    void *trace[16];
    char **messages = (char **)NULL;
    int i, trace_size = 0;

    trace_size = backtrace(trace, 16);
    /* overwrite sigaction with caller's address */
    trace[1] = (void *)ctx.eip;
    messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);
    /* skip first stack frame (points here) */
    printf("[bt] Execution path:\n");
    for (i=1; i<trace_size; ++i)
    {
        printf("[bt] #%d %s\n", i, messages[i]);

        char syscom[256];
        sprintf(syscom,"addr2line %p -e sighandler", trace[i]); 
        system(syscom);
    }
}


void xception::initialize_xception()
{
    /* Install our signal handler */
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = (void *)bt_sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
}
```

THis is giving me the error : `r@r-HP-Mini-110:~/l33t/freeln/Xception/source$ g++ -std=c++11 -g -rdynamic -Wall -o xcep_app application.cpp xception.cpp
xception.cpp: In static member function ‘static void xception::initialize_xception()’:
xception.cpp:38:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’ [-fpermissive]`

Strange thing is that the same thing earlier compiled when placed like as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

void bt_sighandler(int sig, struct sigcontext ctx) 
{

  void *trace[16];
  char **messages = (char **)NULL;
  int i, trace_size = 0;

  trace_size = backtrace(trace, 16);
  /* overwrite sigaction with caller's address */
  trace[1] = (void *)ctx.eip;
  messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);
  /* skip first stack frame (points here) */
  printf("[bt] Execution path:\n");
  for (i=1; i<trace_size; ++i)
  {
      printf("[bt] #%d %s\n", i, messages[i]);

      char syscom[256];
      sprintf(syscom,"addr2line %p -e sighandler", trace[i]); //last parameter is the name of this app
      system(syscom);
  }

}


int func_a(int a, char b) {

  char *p = (char *)0xdeadbeef;

  //a = a + b;
  //*p = 10;  /* CRASH here!! */
  a =9;

  return 2*a;
}


int func_b() {

  int res, a = 5;

  res = 5 + func_a(a, 't');

  raise(SIGUSR1);

  return res;
}


int main() {

  /* Install our signal handler */
  struct sigaction sa;

  sa.sa_handler = (void *)bt_sighandler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

  //sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
  /* ... add any other signal here */

  /* Do something */
  printf("%d\n", func_b());

  printf("%s\n", "not dead yet :)");
}
```

Can you please point me out my mistake ?

Comment: Why are you casting to `void *`?

Comment: I don't believe your older code compiled, assuming you used the same compiler settings. Your older code contains exactly the same error. It will produce exactly the same error message.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ok, I removed it; but now I am getting this error : `error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(int, sigcontext)’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @Ritwik G: Sighandler must be a function with one `int` parameter. You are using a function with two `int` parameters. This will not work regardless of how you slice it.

Comment: @AndreyT I used gcc to compile that older program. You can try it. just save the file as `sig.c` and use : `gcc -g -Wall sig2.c -o sr -rdynamic`

Comment: @RitwikG In C, `void *` can be implicitly converted to any data pointer type (and to any function pointer type as well under POSIX). In C++, that's not possible.

Comment: @Ritwik G: `sig.c`? Using `.c` extension suggests that you compiled it as C language file. C and C++ are significantly different languages. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: @AndreyT I found the solution to my problem in C and now I want to use it in my existing c++ class. So, I guess I am trying to use both. Can you please suggest what I might do in this case.

Comment: @H2CO3 What is the correct way to assign a signal handler to a sigaction handler member in C++ ? or is that simply not recommended/allowed/possible ?

Comment: @Ritwik G: See my answer. What you are trying to do (directly) is impossible. You need an alternative solution, but you have to explain what you are trying to do first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of how you slice it, you cannot use

```
void bt_sighandler(int sig, struct sigcontext ctx)
```

function where a `void (int)` callback is required. You might succeed in suppressing error messages by using casts, which will make the code to formally "compile", but this will not make your program work in any meaningful sense of the word "work".

Function for `sa.sa_handler` callback must be a `void (int)` function, period. There's no way around it. If you want to "smuggle" some additional external data into that function, you have to invent an alternative solution. You can't just add arbitrary parameters to callback functions and expect that the caller will somehow magically supply proper arguments for the parameters you added.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand void (int) function. Can you please elaborate. DO I have to write a function with a different return type ? Or do I have to use function pointers ?

Comment: I understood what is wrong, but I cannot understand the solution

Comment: `void (int)` means that your callback function *must* look as follows `void bt_sighandler(int sig)`. That's it. The name can change, but you are only allowed to have *one* parameter if type `int`. And the return type must be `void`. You cannot "request" more parameters.

Comment: thanks, I merely made the struct that I was passing as parameter as a global and things are working like a charm.

Comment: @Ritwik G: It is one way to do it. It is not pretty, but sometimes it is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

The `sa_handler` member of `struct sigaction` is a function pointer of type `void(*) (int)`. In contrast, the type of the expression `(void *)ctx.eip` is `void *` because of the cast. In C++, implicit conversion from `void *` to another pointer type does not happen, hence the error.

Comment: Can you please suggest how I might fix it ?

Comment: @RitwikG What you want doesn't really make sense. You may have to write a wrapper function because the signature of the two functions isn't the same.

Comment: I merely made the parameter I was passing as global. I know it is ugly, but for now things are working well. Thanks for your help bro.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in **C** you can implicitly convert a `void *` to any other pointer type, while in **C++** you cannot.

In **C++** you need an explicit cast to the actual function type (`void (*)(int)`) to make it not an error.

Note that in both **C** and **C++** converting a `void *` to a function pointer is undefined behavior, but will usually work if the `void *` was converted from a compatible function pointer in the first place.  In addition, a function pointer is only guarenteed to be completely compatible if all the argument types are exactly the same, though you can often get something that appears to work with different argument types (undefined behavior again).

Comment: Formally C does not support implicit conversion of `void *` to function pointer types. I.e. the OP's C version is formally non-compilable as well. The only reason it compiled is because the compiler was used in "loose and permissive error checking" mode.

Comment: @AndreyT: conversion of `void *` to a function pointer is undefined behavior -- the compiler is not required to diagnose it as an error.  Most compilers allow it as it was legal prior to C99 -- the C99 working group broke this part of the language when the tried to more precisely define what an 'object' is.

Comment: @ChrisDodd POSIX requires an implicit conversion from `void *` to a function pointer type to be well-defined (at least in C), however.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: Are you implying that in C89/90 function type qualified as an *object type*? I don't see it in C89/90. Actually, I see a clearly intended distinction between *object types* and *function types* there. And even if function type were an object type in C89/90, it would look like a defect to me. The fact that "most C compilers allow it" means very little. "Most C compilers" allow lots of blatant errors to slip through. In case of GCC `-pedantic-errors` is absolutely required to make it at least close to proper C.

Comment: @Andry: C89 is unclear as to whether function types are a subset of objects types or disjoint; it can be read either way.  But the ability to cast function pointers to void pointers and back and have them work is a crucial part of historic C -- so much so that any compiler that didn't support it would be rejected as unusable.  It even leaks into C++11, with the special proviso that lambdas can be converted to function pointers if and only if they have no captures.  That's because function pointers MUST be able to fit in a single pointer (so that conversions to `void *` and back can work)...